# Access Violation - how do I track down the cause?

Tags: delphi, debugging, access-violation, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm getting an access violation when I close a form in my application.  It seems to happen only after I have access a database a couple of times, but that doesn't seem to make sense.

I have traced through and put outputdebugstring messages in all the related OnDestroy() methods, but the AV appears to be outside of my code.

This is the text of the message:

> Access violation at address 00405F7C in module
>   'MySoopaApplication.exe'. Read of address 00000008.

How do I find where in the application 00405F7C is?

What tools are available in Delphi 10.1 Berlin to help me with this?

Edit: added a bit more info ... when clicking "Break" the IDE always takes me to this piece of code in GETMEM.INC:

```
@SmallPoolWasFull:
  {Insert this as the first partially free pool for the block size}
  mov ecx, TSmallBlockType[ebx].NextPartiallyFreePool
```

Further edit:  well, I found the culprit, though I can't honestly say that the debug tools got me there - they just seemed to indicate it wasn't in my code.

I had used code from the net that I used to find the Windows logged in user - this is it:

```
function GetThisComputerName: string;
var
  CompName: PChar;
  maxlen: cardinal;
begin
  maxlen := MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH +1;
  GetMem(CompName, maxlen);
  try
    GetComputerName(CompName, maxlen);
    Result := CompName;
  finally
    FreeMem(CompName);
  end;
end;
```

once I had replaced the code with a simple result := '12345' the AVs stopped.  I have no changed it to this code:

```
function GetThisComputerName: string;
var
  nSize: DWord;
  CompName: PChar;
begin
  nSize := 1024;
  GetMem(CompName, nSize);
  try
    GetComputerName(CompName, nSize);
    Result := CompName;
  finally
    FreeMem(CompName);
  end;
end;
```

which seems to work and, as a bonus, doesn't cause AVs.

Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: Under Tools|Options in the IDE go to Embarcadero Debuggers | Language Exceptions and make sure Notify on Language Exceptions is checked.  Allow the exception to happen, then go to View | Debug Windows | Call stack and you should be able to see exactly where it occurred.  The fact that it occurs after db access is probably because that causes some object to be created which generates the AV when it is destroyed.  Possibly because it is being Free()ed twice.

Comment: @MartynA: I think that could be an answer.

Comment: Use madExcept or similar

Comment: SizeOf(char) is 2. Hence the heap corruption. No need for heap allocation. Use a stack allocated array.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan IOW, `GetMem()` is being used to allocate only half of what is being reported to `GetComputerName()`, and it is actually writing more than was allocated. Makes sense now that I see that. I didn't notice that earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under `Tools|Options` in the IDE go to `Embarcadero Debuggers | Language Exceptions` and make sure `Notify on Language Exceptions` is checked. Also under `Project Options | Compiling`, make sure `Debugging | Use debug DCUs` is checked.

Allow the exception to happen, then go to `View | Debug Windows | Call stack` and you should be able to see exactly where it occurred. The fact that it occurs after db access is probably because that causes some object to be created which generates the AV when it is destroyed. Possibly because it is being `Free()`ed twice.

If that doesn't solve it, you may may need an exception-logging tool like madExcept mentioned by DavidH.

> Read of address 00000008.

The fact that this address is a low number is suggestive of it being the address of a member of an object (because they are typically at low offsets from the base address of the object).

> How do I find where in the application 00405F7C is?

With your app running, in the IDE go to `Search | Go to Address`.  This should find it if the exception is in your application and not in some related module like a .DLL it is using.  The menu item is enabled once the application is running in the IDE and stopped at a breakpoint.  Also there is a compiler command line switch to find an error by address.

Comment: Thanks for this, @MartynA - had been looking at the call stack, which wasn't making much sense.  Go to Address is greyed out for me :/  Time for madExcept, I think.  Thanks again,

Comment: I've added Use debug DCUs to my answer - usually errors arising from double-frees, etc, are easier to find if you use the versions of the VCL DCUs which contain debug info..  If Go to Address is greyed out, check that you have all the debugging info options turned on.

Comment: @KenWhite:  Thanks, I've added a mention of this in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Others have explained how to diagnose an AV.

Regarding the code itself, there are issues with it:

1. Most importantly, you are not allocating enough memory for the buffer.  `GetMem()` operates on bytes but `GetComputetName()` operates on characters, and in this case `SizeOf (Char)` is 2 bytes. So you are actually allocating half the number of bytes that you are reporting to `GetComputerName()`, so if it writes more than you allocate then it will corrupt heap memory.  The corruption went away when you over-allocated the buffer.  So take `SizeOf(Char)` into account when allocating:

   ```
   function GetThisComputerName: string;
   var
     CompName: PChar;
     maxlen: cardinal;
   begin
     maxlen := MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH +1;
     GetMem(CompName, maxlen * SizeOf(Char)); // <-- here
     try
       GetComputerName(CompName, maxlen);
       Result := CompName;
     finally
       FreeMem(CompName);
     end;
   end;
   ```

In addition to that:

2. you are ignoring errors from `GetComputerName()`, so you are not guaranteeing that `CompName` is even valid to pass to `Result` in the first place.
3. You should use `SetString(Result, CompName, nSize)` instead of `Result := CompName`, since `GetComputerName()` outputs the actual `CompName` length. There is no need to waste processing time having the RTL calculate the length to copy when you already know the length. And since you don't check for errors, you can't rely on `CompName` being null terminated anyway if `GetComputerName()` fails.
4. You should get rid of `GetMem()` altogether and just use a static array on the stack instead:

   ```
   function GetThisComputerName: string;
   var
     CompName: array[0..MAX_COMPUTERNAME_LENGTH] of Char;
     nSize: DWORD;
   begin
     nSize := Length(CompName);
     if GetComputerName(CompName, nSize) then
       SetString(Result, CompName, nSize)
     else
       Result := '';
   end;
   ```

Comment: The heap corruption is due to SizeOf(char) being 2

Comment: Also, if the function succeeds, it guarantees that the buffer is null terminated

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, but not if the function fails, and the original code was not checking for that. I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: Obviously you don't do anything with the buffer when the function fails. Nobody is suggesting that. SetString is better since there's no need to hunt for the terminator. But you can rely on it being there.

Comment: Thank you @RemyLebeau for explaining the problems with the code.  Above and beyond the call of duty. Very kind. Regards,

Comment: Thank you @DavidHeffernan for your contributions throughout this question. Regards,